# Unable to run protractor Test Script

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor

I am using Protractor and trying to run in IE Browsers.

I used this code:

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    'version': '11'
  }
};
```

and I am not left with any errors but IE browser is not opening or running.

Comment: post webdriver log please and protractor/node versions

Comment: Web Driver log :
selenium standalone version available: 3.6.0 [last]
[18:54:54] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.33 [last]
[18:54:54] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.19.0 [last]
[18:54:54] I/status - IEDriverServer is not present

Protractor :  Version 5.1.2
node Version : v6.11.4

Comment: @Aswini : `IEDriverServer is not present` ... guess, that speaks for itself. You can install it via command line `webdriver-manager update --ie`. That should do the trick.
Let me know, if it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Do this workaround and check

```
          In IE -> Internet Options -> Click on Advanced -> In Security Section - > Uncheck enable Enhanced Protected Mode option
```

If it was enabled previously

Comment: I run webdriver-manager update --ie and i unchecked enable protected mode option . after this it is displaying below error message.Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zon
es. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones